# Supervisors lies about company policy

Tags: management

My supervisor instructed me not to go to human resources without informing the supervisor first, and lied stating it is company policy.  This was said to me in hearing range of one of the managers in my chain of command.  When I asked in writing for the policy in writing, the supervisor lied in writing and denied giving me those instructions and cc'd management.  Instead of what I was told, in writing changed the language to state it was requested as a favor. This written reply from my supervisor was done five days later while I was out on a medical leave. To my knowledge, management has not addressed the issue.  Now I am working in an environment where I cannot trust the managers in my chain of command. What steps should take to protect myself from a bullying supervisor who has management's support?

Comment: what is the issue that you wanted to get HR involved in?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you did the right thing by asking in writing and getting the answer in writing. When you ask in writing, cc: the management, too. Any answer that you get from the supervisor and that you don't like, echo the answer back in an email and cc: the management. That should keep your supervisor on the straight and narrow.

@WesleyLong makes the following recommendation, which I strongly support: "Remember to keep that documentation offsite. Getting emails is great, but if you're terminated and locked out of that email account, it's as though you never had them. Forward and BCC to a GMail account, or something similar, as long as nothing in the employee handbook precludes that" The email that you forward to yourself would bcc's (Blnd Carbon Copy)

Comment: +1 - keeping a written record of things a great start when handling such situations. You can always pull out the written record if people try to lie or obfuscate.

Comment: @Vector with pathological liars kind of shows. Work with enough people, and you'll meet some outliers :)

Comment: I once worked with a guy who documented **everything**. At every meeting or important conversation, he was busy taking copious notes. It served him very well many a time...

Comment: Remember to keep that documentation offsite.  Getting emails is great, but if you're terminated and locked out of that email account, it's as though you never had them.  Forward and BCC to a GMail account, or something similar, as long as nothing in the employee handbook precludes that.

Comment: @WesleyLong I incorporated your comment into my answer, with full attribution to you,of course :)

Comment: I am not sure if I agree sending work emails to a personal email account.  Furthermore its been proven that Google and others will disable access to the email if requested by a company.  I would agree with creating a hard copy of the email.

Comment: @Ramhound - perhaps I should have been more verbose.  Back in the olden days when we had to pull the string really tight to get an Internet connection over 20 Kbps, we had this thing called POP3 where we'd actually pull email down onto our own computers.  No, really, it's true!  :)

Comment: Yes;  I suppose POP3 would solve the problem I describe provided you downloaded the email BEFORE access to it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to respond and advise without knowing what country you're in; but there's always going to a labor ombudsman (if such a thing exists for your jurisdiction) and checking with them to see what your local legal rules and regulations are. Once you have a bit more information, then you'll be better prepared to plan and take action.

From the details you've provided, this sounds like it could be - in the worst extreme - an abusive situation. (I'm visualizing two scenarios here, on opposite ends of the "alarm" spectrum: a supervisor who has harassed you and doesn't want it reported up the chain; or a supervisor who doesn't want you talking repeatedly to HR about non-bullying disputes within the team, which they want to manage within the team to avoid drawing negative attention to themself or the team.) Again going just on what you've provided here, this might be a situation that you can't salvage, you can only ride out.

If I were in a situation like this, I would continue working, quietly update my resume in preparation to finding a new job, and also prepare to keep documentation of all interactions with management from this point forward - ie - printouts that you take with you, emails that you bcc to a personal account, something that gives you copies of all documentation of the incidents in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are in very difficult situation, I agree - "been there, down that", and the end was not pretty.

Depending on the structure of the firm you work for, sometimes turning directly to HR can help - that is one of things they are there for: To provide a venue for employees to register complaints and express grievances about abusive workplace situations and potential violations of company policy. Far too often, however, that isn't much of a remedy: HR will be very pleasant and accommodating, pay "lip service" to your complaint, and then file it away and forget about it as soon as you leave the room...

If you run into the same sort of disingenuous/evasive behavior at HR as you did with those directly above you in the chain of command, then you're working at a bad firm - try to expedite your exit, as per my conclusion, and @Leigh's answer.

Another way of working things, depending on your friends and connections in the firm (as well as its structure) is to skip a level or two - try turning to the manager's manager or someone else "higher up" who knows you and values and respects you and your work as an employee. I have done that a few times, and it worked - for a while... But it's risky - you need to be good at office politics to get it right.

Bottom line is that unfortunately, I have to agree with @Leigh's conclusion: Be diligent in your documentation (you seem to be on the right track in that respect) and quietly prepare for an exit - your situation may be approaching toxicity.